# Error when I try to create sub menu in sale menu openerp 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm try to create a sub menu in sale menu in my custom module, just after product link, but it doesn't appear..

In my module, after install it, I see the name of my menu in "Created menu".

I try just with this code in my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>
            <menuitem name="Gamme" id="menu_gamme" parent="base.menu_product"/>
        </data>
    </openerp>
```

or with this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>
            <menuitem name="Gamme" id="menu_gamme" parent="base.menu_product"/>

            <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_gamme">
               <field name="name">Gamme</field>
               <field name="model">gamme</field>
               <field name="view_type">tree</field>
               <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            </record>
        </data>
    </openerp>
```

but with latest I have this error :

```
    ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: ailailail.action_gamme
```

Comment: is this your whole code?

Comment: yes it's just to test the sub menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes to your code .
You need have action value in your menu tag that takes the id of your ir.actiona.act_windows record. It will automatically take the name "Gamme" from the field name mentioned in the record, you dont need to specify it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>
            <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_gamme">
               <field name="name">Gamme</field>
               <field name="model">gamme</field>
               <field name="view_type">tree</field>
               <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            </record>
            <menuitem action="action_gamme" id="menu_gamme" parent="base.menu_product"/>
        </data>
    </openerp>
```

Hope this helps....